# How to build many to many product database into pimcore?

Tags: many-to-many, product, pimcore

I have to build a product repository in pimcore. I have clear design of database but I do not know how make it in pimcore in recommended/optimize way.

```
Category :
    id
    name

Attribute :
    id
    cat_id
    name

Product
    id
    cat_id
    name

ProdAttributes
    id
    prod_id
    attr_id
    attr_value
```

I can build Object classes for all and set relation within them, But if that is recommended way ?

Also I need to build REST API for inserting & fetch data. I assuming I need to do some ZF1 DB code instead of using pimcore Object API ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using [pimcore's GUI](https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE3/Object+Classes). That's the best way.

Ad REST: there's allready an RESTful API in pimcore. You can find the documentation [here](https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE3/REST+Webservice).
If you need more you'll have to build your own. [I've put mine on GitHub](https://github.com/StephanWeinhold/pimcore-api). It fetches data from an object and returns them via JSON or XML - maybe it helps.